# How to delete leading and trailing characters from string?

Tags: python, replace, split, whitespace

I have this code:

```
    for item in items:
        currency_name = item.text
        currency_name.split('\n')
        comps.append({
            'currency_name': currency_name
        })

    print(comps)
```

and this is my print(comps):

```
{'currency_name': '\n\n                     Австралійський долар                   \n'}, {'currency_name': '\n\n                     Азербайджанський манат                   \n'},
```

How else can I delete this \n and space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `str.strip`:

```py
...

currency_name = item.text
comps.append({
    "currency_name": currency_name.strip()
})

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `currency_name.split('\n')` this line is redundant - you just throw away the returned list.

That said `str.strip()` method would do `'currency_name': currency_name.strip()`

However, assuming this is part of scrapping and using Beautiful Soup, there is convenient [stripped_strings()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=stripped#strings-and-stripped-strings) method

So

```
comps = []
for item in items:
    comps.append({'currency_name': next(item.stripped_strings())})

print(comps)
```

or

```
comps = [{'currency_name': next(item.stripped_strings())} for item in items]
print(comps)
```